# Как распарсить несколько файлов одновременно с помощью модуля argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

Есть файлы summon.txt, summon_2.txt, summon_3.txt.

Написан вот такой код:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f', dest='some_file', action='store', default='summon.txt')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Этот код позволяет парсить только один файл за раз. А нужно, чтобы можно было парсить одновременно все.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить параметр `nargs='*'`, чтобы можно было указать 0 и более файлов, либо `nargs='+'`, если должно быть указано не менее одного файла:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f', nargs='*', dest="files", default=['summon.txt'], help='A list of files to process')

args = parser.parse_args(["-f", "summon.txt", "summon_2.txt", "summon_3.txt"])
print(args)  # Вывод: Namespace(files=['summon.txt', 'summon_2.txt', 'summon_3.txt'])

args = parser.parse_args(["-f"])
print(args)  # Вывод: Namespace(files=[]) (считается, что передан список из нуля файлов)

args = parser.parse_args([])  # Если -f не передано вообще, то используется default значение
print(args)  # Вывод: Namespace(files=['summon.txt'])
```

См. [argparse, nargs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs)